Adding checkbox to Output Panel
I'm working on pipeline integration addon for a studio. It resolves variables in output path. Everything works nicely. But i want to add little checkbox below the Blender's parameter that would show to user resolved path when checked.
Is it possible to inject something to the existing UI panel? Or override it?
Thanks

Yes, use append or prepend
e.g. bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.append() or bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.prepend()
check the addon_add_object.py Python template

thank you! append worked perfectly
